# Efficient JS Event Listener on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I have written the following script, and it is perfectly working.

```
function LogoHoverAdd() {
    this.classList.add("logo__container--hover");
}
function LogoHoverRemove() {
    this.classList.remove("logo__container--hover");
}

var logo = document.querySelector("h1");
logo.addEventListener("mouseover", LogoHoverAdd);
logo.addEventListener("mouseout", LogoHoverRemove);
```

I think, this method is very inefficient, since I have to implement a few of these event listeners. Therefore, I have tried to make this shorter by putting it together or using the `ClassList Toggle` function. Unfortunately, it has not worked yet.

How do I write this piece of code in a good way?

[[I am not using jquery.]]

Comment: Can you share the HTML? It sounds like you don't need JS at all, CSS has a built in hover detection `h1:hover` would be all you need if all you really want to do is add some styles on hover.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your current code. The only thing I would change is to use the `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`

Comment: Ok, I will try `mouseenter`. By the way, I have shortened the code, so I have to do some other tasks within the same function.

Comment: My aim would be a function "ToggleClass(classname)" to minize the code lines. But I do not get it....

Comment: Is your goal in particular to write nice looking Javascript around those two event listeners?

Comment: Thank you for your time! The nice look is not primary, important would be the code line reduction / simplification, because I could **reuse** the Toggle Function for lots of other elements.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope I understood your question correctly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it has become clear this is a Javascript question, here is a way you can create reusable functions.

```js
function hover(element, enter, leave){
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter)
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave)
}
```

You can then pass your element and callback functions like so.

```js
hover(document.querySelector('h1'), e => {
  // On hover
  e.target.classList.add("logo__container--hover")
}, e => {
  // On exit hover
  e.target.classList.remove("logo__container--hover")
})
```

You can reduce the lines of code too by modifying the hover function.

```js
function hover(element, className){
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => element.classList.add(className))
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => element.classList.remove(className))
}
```

Then use it like so.

```js
hover(document.querySelector('h1'), "logo__container--hover")
```

You can reuse this now for multiple elements scalably.

---

This was my previous answer: As JHeth mentioned, use [CSS pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) instead.

```css
h1{
  /* Style when not hovering */
}

h1:hover{
  /* Style when cursor is on element */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike! It is the perfect solution!

Comment: Sure thing, michael!